# How to match filenames in file with a C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract MP3 filenames from binary file. I'm trying to get this regular expression to match all MP3 and WAVE files. Here is what I have so far:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection  m = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(rosText, @"(\w:\\(?:\w+(?:\s+\w+)*\\)*[-_\w\s\d.\(\)\'\[\]]*\.mp3)",System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

MATCHES

> C:\mp3\Miami House\New Adds 49\Jungle_EP_(Life_In_The_Jungle_'Original_Mix')-SL-51-1(320k).mp3

DOES NOT MATCH

> C:\mp3\Miami House\New Adds 49\Each_&_Every_Day_Pt.*2*(Raw_Artistic_Soul_Vocal_Mix)-AR002-1(320k).mp3
>
> C:\mp3\Miami House\New Adds C:\mp3\Miami House\New Adds 49\Jungle_EP_(Life_In_The_Jungle_'Original_Mix')-SL-51-1(320k).wav

File example here (in UTF-8): http://savinet.net/fileexample.txt

Comment: Are you working with the file system directly? Why not just check the file extension? You can do this via `FileInfo` or using methods on the `Path` class, and you can get the file name using `.Name` on FileInfo or using `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` (or something like that)

Comment: Im reading binary files and extracting the ASCII filenames.. I know about the filesystem. Thanks

Comment: example of your binary file?

Comment: "\r@\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\b03/13/10\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\n\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0�X�K\0\0\n\0\0\0GULP�\0\0^\0\0\0C:\\mp3\\Miami House\\New Adds 49\\Jungle_EP_(Life_In_The_Jungle_'Original_Mix')-SL-51-1(320k).mp3\0\0\0\0\0\0?\0\0\0Jungle_EP_(Life_In_The_Jungle_'Original_Mix')-SL-51-1(320k).mp3\0\b\0\0\0Arnaud D\0\0\0\0Jungle EP (Life In The Jungle\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\04�\0\0\0\0\0\0�\0\0\0ʁ\0\0�\0\0\0\0@\0\0\0ENON\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0^\0\0\0

Comment: There is a char limit

Comment: @TimDavis: Don't you have a library that supports decoding the file and returning a list of filenames?

Answer (score 0):

A very simple regex to match such files is:

```
string regex = @".*\.(mp3|wav)"
```

If you are however able to extract the files (in this case in the `/tmp` directory) into a directory you can use:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles ("/tmp", "*.mp3")) {
    try {
        //do something
    } catch {
        ; // optionally report error
    }
}
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles ("/tmp", "*.wav")) {
    try {
        //do something
    } catch {
        ; // optionally report error
    }
}
```

as well.

Comment: Im not reading directories.. I know its easy when using the filesystem.. I am not using the file system.. I am reading a Binary file and must extract filenames from the binary file. The only way is through REGEX

Comment: But I assume the binary format provides information when a filename begins. Otherwise you make the assumption on how a filename will look like and for instance Mac OS X and Linux name the files differently. And in some distant future, it is quite possible that the filenames will look completely different. Can you provide more info on how the binary format works?

Comment: I have attached a link to the sample file translated to UTF-8. This is a windows program and files will all look like DRIVE:\path\filename.ext

Comment: Yes but what are the specifications of the binary file? Is it for instance a concatenation of `<FILENAME><FILESIZE><DATA>` because in that case one knows the next name comes after the `<FILESIZE>` number of bytes. Say I include a file that ends with `C:\\`, this will become problematic...